# bus monitor for cocotb

Tags: vhdl, monitor, verification, cocotb

I am trying to setup Cocotb as my verification environment.
I have been looking at the examples, that are useful, but I am not sure about direction I should go.

My block can be seen as:

- 4 busses in input
- 1 clock and 1 reset as inputs
- 2 busses in output

The output are the result of a combinational and sequential processing of the input signals.

The part I lack to go further is how to define correctly monitor for my inputs and output busses, that are (as far as I understand) not compliant with AvalonST

I looked at the examples provided with Cocotb, and what prevents me to get inspired is that the provided either:

- have no monitor (like adder)
- use AvalonST drivers (like endianswapper)

The questions I have at the moment are:

- When looking at the mean example, I see that the person has defined its own `StreamBusMonitor`, and I should do the same in my understanding (to monitor my 4 inputs to feed my reference model). AM I correct?
- I don't understand how the names of the signals are matched by the `StreamBusMonitor` I see the following line:
  `dut_out = StreamBusMonitor(dut, "o", dut.clk)`
  but I don't understand the purpose of the "o", and where in the StreamBusMonitor it is used. Could someone help me?
- I haven't found any official Cocotb forum. Is there a more official place to ask my beginner questions about Cocotb than StackOverflow?

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: You could ask this at that [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/vhdl/General). You can also look into our 3 Cocotb testbenches provided in our [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC?ts=2): [PoC.cache.par](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/tb/cache/cache_par_cocotb.py?ts=2), [PoC.sort.lur_cache](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/tb/sort/sort_lru_cache_cocotb.py?ts=2) or [PoC.sort.lru_list](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/tb/sort/sort_lru_list_cocotb.py?ts=2).

Comment: Yes you need to write your own `Monitor` and `Transaction` classes.

Answer (score 1):

The `StreamBusMonitor` is based on the `BusMonitor` class which is defined in `cocotb/monitors/__init__.py`

The beginning of the class definition looks like this:

```
class BusMonitor(Monitor):
    """
    Wrapper providing common functionality for monitoring busses
    """
    _signals = []
    _optional_signals = []

    def __init__(self, entity, name, clock, reset=None, reset_n=None,
                 callback=None, event=None):
        self.log = SimLog("cocotb.%s.%s" % (entity._name, name))
        self.entity = entity
        self.name = name
        self.clock = clock
        self.bus = Bus(self.entity, self.name, self._signals,
                       optional_signals=self._optional_signals)
        self._reset = reset
        self._reset_n = reset_n
        Monitor.__init__(self, callback=callback, event=event)
```

The `"o"` in the `StreamBusMonitor` constructor is the `name` argument. That is used in determining the full name of the signals when it's passed to the `Bus` constructor.

You're probably aware that a fairly sensible and common bus naming scheme is the bus protocol signal names with some unique identifier appended or prepended, like "i" for in, "o" for out, or 'axi_m' for an AXI master, etc. and that's exactly what cocotb assumes is going on.

The signals for the `StreamBusMonitor` are declared and override the `BusMonitor`'s `_signals` and `_optional_signals` values. So the signals defined here:

```
class StreamBusMonitor(BusMonitor):
    """
    streaming bus monitor
    """
    _signals = ["valid", "data"]
```

essentially have the `"o"` attached to the name (prepend with `_` joining the signals and the bus name is the default behavior as per `cocotb/bus.py`) to determine the bus signal names in the design, and the handle to the correct object in the design hierarchy is the `entity` argument.

Which makes sense, as the signals declared are those above, and the signals in the VHDL are:

```
  i_valid  : in  std_logic;
  i_data   : in  t_data_array(0 to BUS_WIDTH-1);
  o_valid  : out std_logic;
  o_data   : out t_data
```

As for a communication channel there is now a gitter channel:

https://gitter.im/cocotb

and a mailing list set up by LibreCores:

https://lists.librecores.org/listinfo/cocotb